# Moment timezone is confusing, no idea how to make it work

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have a UTC timestamp coming from the database

My local time here is America/Vancouver.

So for example, in the database, I have

```
   2018-12-26 08:28:00
```

I want this to display as

```
2018-12-25 12:28:00
```

8 hours ahead.

Currently I have done this

```
return moment(timestamp).tz('America/Vancouver').format()
```

And this returns

```
2018-12-26 08:28:00 -08:00
```

Which is correct, its showing the - eight hours.  But how do I get it to actually display this as the correct time, including that 8 hour offset?

I thought moment was supposed to do that for you automatically?  But it doesnt seem to.

```
 moment(timestamp).tz('America/Vancouver').fromNow()
```

gives me "In 8 hours".  Whereas it should give me "11 minutes ago"

How do I get moment-timezone to actually do its thing??
According to examples what Im doing should be working, but its not.

For exmaple.

```
return moment(timestamp).tz('America/Vancouver').format('MM-DD-YYYY H:i:s)
```

returns

```
12-26-2018 08:26:00
```

Which is the UTC value, not the offseted Vancouver value??? What gfives?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Moment.js will parse dates with timezone which it can detect on your computer. if you need parse UTC date you need use .utc method.

```
moment.utc(timestamp).tz('America/Vancouver').format()
```